# Blog page error 'Index of /blog'

Tags: posts

A friend has reached out to me for help and thus far I have been unable to figure out what the problem is - his (outdated no longer supported) theme is not displaying his blog - when you click on the blog page it is only showing index page that has nothing on it. Any ideas of what may be wrong? The blog folder in the file manager is empty, but the blog posts populate fine on the homepage when it is set to do so via customizer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a blog folder in the file manager.

If there is one, your web server will load that instead of asking WordPress for the blog page. Delete the empty folder and it will work. You should never need to create folders or pages in the file manager or via FTP when using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

This worked!!! Thank you. (see below for post I found). For those that don't know how to get to the "blog" folder to delete, the way I did it was to go into the File Manager in the cPanel in your hosting. Once you are there you most likely need to click "public_html" then click on your domain name. If you see the "blog" folder listed on the right delete it.